# Animated Widget using PNGs in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-animation

I want to create a widget that animates using PNG images in `xamarin` android. Functionality as follows,
*First click on the image view in widget starts animation of changing PNGs.
*On the last PNG, I want to show a test view with text.

I followed https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/ to create the widget.
and I added the click event like this code https://github.com/nguyenthanhliemfc/WidgetButtonClick

I did not found a good solution to this requirement. please help me with this.

### balance_widget.xaml

```
    android:id="@+id/widgetBackground">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="72dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widgetAnnouncementIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/announcement" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widgetMedium"
            android:text="HelloAppWidget" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widgetSmall"
            android:text="Last refresh: 00:00" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### appwidgetprovider.xml in the /Resources/XML/ folder

```
    android:minWidth="288dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    android:minResizeWidth="144dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/Widget"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/previewImage" />
```

### AppWidget.cs

```
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/appwidgetprovider")]
public class AppWidget : AppWidgetProvider
{
    public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    var me = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
    appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(me, BuildRemoteViews(context, appWidgetIds));
}

private RemoteViews BuildRemoteViews(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.blance_widget);

    SetTextViewText(widgetView);
    RegisterClicks(context, appWidgetIds, widgetView);

    return widgetView;
}
private void SetTextViewText(RemoteViews widgetView)
{
    widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, "HelloAppWidget");
    widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall,
        string.Format("Last update: {0:H:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now));
}
private static string AnnouncementClick = "AnnouncementClickTag";

private void RegisterClicks(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews widgetView)
{
    widgetView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widgetAnnouncementIcon,
        GetPendingSelfIntent(context, AnnouncementClick));
}

private PendingIntent GetPendingSelfIntent(Context context, string action)
{
    var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
    intent.SetAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    base.OnReceive(context, intent);

    // Check if the click is from the "Announcement" button
    if (AnnouncementClick.Equals(intent.Action))
    {
        // Open another app
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What kind of animation are you wanting? Also, is there a fixed number of images, or can it vary?

Comment: @MikeM. There is fixed number of images (21) one for start, if i click on that image other 20 images shows one after other like a animation till the last one with a textview.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that I had a relatively simple idea for you, but the more I think about, I realize that it would take some creative fiddling to get it to work as you're wanting. In any case, [`ViewFlipper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) is what I was thinking of, as it can animate automatically between any children you'd want to put in it. And it's allowed in `RemoteViews`, but the fact that it would be in one is what makes it a little tricky.

Comment: Actually, it might not be too terribly tricky, but you'd need some sort of timer mechanism to advance the current child as needed.

Comment: @MikeM.thank you i will look into this. is there any tutorial you recommend for this ?

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of. I have a relatively simple example of a `ViewFlipper` in an App Widget from a previous question, though, that might help with the general setup: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Dk9YkcqxBgjEzW3Oi6P8X3gfmQ032Hw/view?usp=drivesdk. That flips back and forth between only two children upon clicking, but it should give you the general idea. Also, it's in Java, but it looks like you probably know Java better than I know Xamarin, anyway.

Comment: @MikeM.Thank you very much. I will look into this. i am very grateful for this idea.

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT look into this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748537/auto-flipping-view-flipper-in-remote-view-app-widget`